# WCF JSON Web service, issues moving from GET to POST

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asp-classic

My URL path components are too long and I am trying to change the method from GET to POST.  I am getting deserialization issues.  Here is the service

```
    public class AppUser : IAppUser
{
    //[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddShop/{shop}")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddShop")]
    List<fme.AppUserResult> services.IAppUser.AddShop(string shop)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        fme.AppUser oUser = jss.Deserialize<fme.AppUser>(shop);

        return oUser.Add();         
    }       
}
```

and here is the request (it worked with GET if it was under 260 characters)

```
{"shopCity":"City","shopState":"State","shopPhone":"Phone","shopName":"Name","shopEmail":"Email","shopHours":"Hours","shopZip":"Zip","shopAddress":"Street"}
```

I have also tried

```
{"shop":{"shopCity":"City","shopState":"State","shopPhone":"Phone","shopName":"Name","shopEmail":"Email","shopHours":"Hours","shopZip":"Zip","shopAddress":"Street"}}
```

This is the error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The
>   exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of
>   type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected.
>   Found element 'shopCity' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the method is automatically trying to deserialize the json to the type of the parameter. Because it can't deserialize the json to an object of type string it errors. Try changing the parameter type to **fme.AppUser** instead of **string**:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddShop")]
List<fme.AppUserResult> services.IAppUser.AddShop(fme.AppUser oUser)
{
    return oUser.Add();         
}
```